# How to get saved reminders in android in my application

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am trying to develop an application for android, In which I need to get all the calender entries(Reminders), saved in the phone calendar, How can I get them? And Can I do it on android emulator??

Answer (score 0):

GData is both deprecated and not compatible with many Android versions.

Reading [this](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html) will help.

Answer (score -1):

I got this code.See, it may help you

```
Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/events"), new String[]{ "calendar_id", "title", "description", "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }, null, null, null);         
    //Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id", "name" }, null, null, null);
    String add = null;
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String[] CalNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    int[] CalIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < CalNames.length; i++) {
        CalIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
        CalNames[i] = "Event"+cursor.getInt(0)+": \nTitle: "+ cursor.getString(1)+"\nDescription: "+cursor.getString(2)+"\nStart Date: "+new Date(cursor.getLong(3))+"\nEnd Date : "+new Date(cursor.getLong(4))+"\nLocation : "+cursor.getString(5);
        if(add == null)
            add = CalNames[i];
        else{
            add += CalNames[i];
        }           
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.calendars)).setText(add);

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
```

Comment: This is undocumented and unsupported. Google has repeatedly told you to not use undocumented content providers. This code will not work on all versions of Android. This content provider may not even exist on any given device. And Google may close down access to this content provider, as they have with others. Please use the Google Calendar GData API for manipulating a user's Google Calendar.